# Select dynamic option in a table through selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

The login workflow of my test site is as below:

> 1. Login with Username and Password
> 2. Select an Item in the Item list and Submit
> 3. Work on the selected Item
> 4. Go to Subscribe Item page
> 5. Subscribe to another Item and save

The Item list is sorted Alphabetically based on the subscriptions of the User.
My Selenium code is like below works perfectly, till I subscribe another option. The order of my required option (Option 3) changes as it is sorted alphabetically.

```
package mypackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //To wait until the element get visible or invisible.
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
        driver.get("https://arunelias.in/testing/randomoption.php");  
        //For wait until the element get visible.
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("gvItemListing_grdSelect_0")));
        //Select Option 3 displayed and submit
        driver.findElement(By.id("gvItemListing_grdSelect_3")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();
    }

}
```

I have created a sample page https://arunelias.in/testing/randomoption.php  which mimics the Item list.

> - I want to select an option (say Option 3) from the table.
> - How do I will be able to find in which Row my required Option is displayed?
> - How do I will be able to select the radio option displayed beside "*Option 3*".

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) `How do I will be able to [do something]` I feel "syntactically challenged" (lack the smarts to understand this). Can you please try and put this in simple sentences?

Comment: @Arun i have added the solution of your problem. Please check this and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the complete example how you can select radio option based on text beside your radio option.

```
driver.get("https://arunelias.in/testing/randomoption.php");    


WebElement allItems = driver.findElement(By.id("gvItemListing"));


List<WebElement> tableId = allItems.findElements(By.tagName("td"));


String optionString = "Option 3"; 

for(int i = 1 ; i< tableId.size() ; i=i+2){

    if(tableId.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(optionString) ){
        tableId.get(i-1).click();
        break;
    }

}
```

It will click the radio button of **`Option 3`**. If you want to check any other option just put the option Name into

```
String optionString = "Your option name";
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @mahmud-riad, It works. Clicking the entire `<td>` containing the radio option is brilliant! I don't know it will work on all browsers, but it works on Firefox.

Comment: @Arun nice to hear from you. If it works then accept the answer and upvote it. So that others can get help from this

Answer (score 0):

To click on the **`radio button`** with text as **`Option 3`** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.get("https://arunelias.in/testing/randomoption.php");    
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='gvItemListing']/tbody/tr//td[.='Option']"));
for(WebElement option:options)
    if(option.getAttribute("innerHTML").equalsIgnoreCase("Option 3") )
        option.findElement(By.xpath("//self//preceding::input[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB, unfortunately this does not work. I was able to navigate to correct option `Option 3` by changing first xpath to `//table[@id='gvItemListing']/tbody/tr/td`. But clicking the radio button by `click()` is not triggering anything.

Comment: @Arun There was a typo. Check my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Issue was on the relative xpath `//self`. I was able to  make the code work by changing it to `.//preceding::input[1]`. I have suggested an edit also.

Comment: @Arun Great, but I don't see you like the way :)